# Vagrant error when running vagrant up

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, vagrant-windows

Can you help me with this guys? This is so strange, this still works yesterday and i suddenly bump into this error.

[Image here ..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/429Ct.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear Your Temp folder for fix this issue. This is happening because you might not shut it down properly last time.

All you need to do is delete `C://Users/Braudy/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant212XXXX`

Comment: I will try this :) I'll let you know Thanks